# how to pass one regex output to another regex in perl

Tags: perl

How to combine two regex . This is my input:

```
1.UE_frequency_offset_flag  else { 2}   UE_frequency_offset_flag
2.served1   0x00    Uint8,unsigned char
```

```
#my first regex expression is used for extracting the values inside curly braces 
my ($first_match) = /(\b(\d+)\b)/g;
print "$1 \n";
#my second regex expression   
my ($second_match) = / \S \s+ ( \{ [^{}]+ \} | \S+ ) /x;
```

I was trying to combine both regex but did not get the expected output.

```
my ($second_match) = / \S \s+ ( \{ [^{}]+ \} |\b(\d+)\b| \S+ ) /x;
```

My expected output:

```
2,0x00
```

Please help where I am doing mistake?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. What are you trying to capture by the second regex? The string `2,0x00` can't be matched as it doesn't appear in the input string.

Comment: @choroba.I want to combine both the regex

Comment: Yes, but what do you mean by "combine"? It's a broad term. Help us to help you.

Comment: for second regex my ($second_match) = / \S \s+ ( \{ [^{}]+ \} | \S+ ) /x; not extracting value inside  curly braces.so I have added first regex which is my ($first_match) = /(\b(\d+)\b)/g here I am able to extract value in curly braces .can we modify second regex such a way so that it can extract values inside curly braces. or pass the first regex $1 output to second regex.

Comment: I don't see `0x00` in curly brackets in the input. Also, what do you mean by "pass regex output to regex"?

Comment: what I mean capture first regex output in $1 then add $1 in second regex

Comment: You can use it directly: `perl -lwe '"abc" =~ /(.)/; print "cba" =~ /($1)/'` prints `a`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126011/discussion-between-abhishek-and-choroba).

Answer (score 2):

The question is not completely clear to me, because I don't see how you want to combine two regex or pass the output of one to the other.

- If you want to pass the captured part of the first regex then you need to save it to a variable:

  ```
  my ($first_match) = /(\b(\d+)\b)/g;
  my $captured = $1;
  ```

  Then you can place the variable `$captured` in the second regex.
- If you want to use the complete match and search inside that. Then you need to do the following:

  ```
  my ($first_match) = /(\b(\d+)\b)/g;
  print "$1,"; # Don't print one space then new line if you want to have a comma separating the two values
  my ($second_match) = $first_match =~ / \S \s+ ( \{ [^{}]+ \} | \S+ ) /x;
  ```

Based on your input, this won't generate the expected output.

The following code would print out:

```
2,0x00
```

When processing your input.

```
print "$1," if /\{\s*(\d+)\s*\}/;
print "$1\n" if /(\d+x\d+)/;
```